Is it possible to send a pdf file using Postmark using NodeJs
Is there possible way to send an attatchment, pdf or image using postmark using postmark?
So currently, I'm only using postmark for sending email, but is it possible to send a custom pdf using postmark?
await client.sendEmail({
            "From": "mywebsite@support.com",
            "To": email,
            "Subject": "Appointment Confirmation",
            "Attachments": [

            ],
            "TextBody": `

        Dear ${fullname},

        Your appointment has been confirmed with the following details:

        Title: ${title}
        Date: ${event_date.toDateString()}
        Time: ${start_time} - ${end_time}
        Purpose: ${purpose}

        Thank you for using our service.

        Best regards,
        Your Appointment Team

        if you encounter any problem or concern, please email myemail
    `,
            "MessageStream": "outbound",

        },

